# Failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource when loading UIView with Table

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a ViewController in which I put another small UIView in the middle where I have placed a TableView but not sure how to display data from an array in this table, any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm trying to load the table using this code:

```
-(void) animateResults {

_resultsLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Scored %d", runningScore ];

resultsTable.delegate = self;
resultsTable.dataSource = self;
[self.resultsTable registerClass:[UITableViewCell self] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"resultsListCell"];
[self.resultsTable reloadData];
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
    _resultsView.frame = self.view.frame;

} completion:^(BOOL finished){

   NSLog(@"%@", questionsArray);

}];

}
```

But now I'm receiving a Failed to obtain a cell from its dataSource. Heres the code for the table

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
//Return number of sections
return 1;

}

//get number of rows by counting number of challenges
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section {
return questionsArray.count;
}


//setup cells in tableView
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
//setup cell
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"resultsListCell";
resultsViewCell *cell = [tableView  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

NSDictionary *results = [questionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *resultsName = [results objectForKey:@"answers"];

BOOL correct = [[results objectForKey:@"correct"] boolValue];

if (!correct) {
    cell.resultsIcon.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BlackIconLock.png"];
}

else{
    cell.resultsIcon.image = nil;
}

cell.resultsName.text = resultsName;

return cell;
}
```

and heres the .h for this view controller

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Store.h"
#import "flags.h"
#import "Tribes.h"
#import "resultsViewCell.h"

@interface GamePlayViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>{

NSMutableArray *questionsArray;
NSMutableArray *answersArray;
NSInteger gameSelected;
NSMutableArray *revealArray;
NSTimer *questionTimer;
BOOL GameInProgress;

int random;
int questionTimerCounter;
int loopCounter;
int runningScore;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *questionImage;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLabel1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLabel2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *answerLabel3;

- (IBAction)answer1:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)answer2:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)answer3:(id)sender;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cover1;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cover2;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cover3;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cover4;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cover5;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cover6;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cover7;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *cover8;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *coreView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultsLabel;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *resultsTable;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *resultsView;

@end
```

I get this error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell resultsIcon]: unrecognized selector sent to instance"
I'm stuck not sure how to proceed. Thank You in advance for any help or guidance you could provide me.

oh yeah heres the resultsViewCell.h

```
@interface resultsViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *resultsFlag;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *resultsName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *resultsIcon;

@end
```

Comment: I think these `resultsTable.delegate = self;` and `resultsTable.dataSource = self;` should be in `viewDidLoad`. Also if your cell have custom class and custom .xib then u have to register it. If both not true, try NSLog your data out and see if it contains anything

Comment: I'm loading a UIView with a table when I load the delegate and data source. as far as the data from the array, I have logged and it displays that data is in fact ready to load but I'm assuming during the cell load I'm missing something.

Comment: Do u have custom cell class and custom xib for it? If not then make sure that your tableView is not nil by NSLog it before set dataSource and delegate

Comment: Yes I do i just updated the post to reflect the results view cell. h file.

Comment: Try remove `cell.resultsIcon.image...` line in your code and see if it work? Else try to see if u connect wrong IBOutlet or something

Comment: I got rid of the error changing UITableViewCell to resultViewCell the custom cells .h file name. Now I'm getting a NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 10 beyond bounds [0 .. 9]

Comment: check your `questionsArray` again in `cellForRowAtIndexPath `, maybe it's different from your row?, the code you post only got that line is enumerate the array, else it might lie in other enumerate place, when u crash look at the left hand tab, press the line under the crash debug highlight and it will lead u to whatever line causing it

Comment: Figured out by changing UITableViewCell to resultViewCell the final view was not loading so NSRangeException came up. so still stuck same place.

Comment: thank you for all your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the codes above you provided, I assume you are using a custom cell. You should register that **resultsViewCell**

Register that custom cell in **viewDidLoad**

```
[self.resultsTable registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"NAME_OF_YOUR_CELL_NIB" bundle:nil] forCellReuseIdentifier:@"resultsListCell"];
```

And I noticed that  inside your **animateResults** method, you are assigning self to a delegate and datasource of **resultsTable**, shouldn't it be **self.resultsTable** or **_resultsTable**?

Comment: I've updated the post with the suggestion you made and I still get the unrecognized NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell resultsIcon]: unrecognized selector sent to instance. Oh yeah so would i change the self. to self.resultsTable.delegate and eliminate the = self?

Comment: Make sure your custom cell (xib) has its resultsIcon declared in its .h file. You need to register the Nib, I'm not sure if the way you register your custom cell will work. Can you change it to registerNib like the example I provided above? And how about the resultsTable thing I asked in my answer?

Comment: Im not using a nib file just storyboard

Comment: In that case, you can just drag your custom cell in your Storyboard to your UITableView that is in your Storyboard as well. Doing so will not require you to register the custom cell.

Comment: Welcome Joe. You might want to accept an answer for this question of yours.

Comment: I would but I'm still stuck on stupid, I have tried all the suggestions but my table still won't populate. Your suggestion actually solved an error I received so I'll mark your answer.

Answer (score 0):

First check your `questionArray`. It must not have any empty object.

Second if you are using cell from storyboard means direct from `tableview`, then why are you registering it?